# C# Programmatically created datagridview - DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cellValueChanged check state always returning FALSE

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In C#, I cannot get DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn event to work. It always get a FALSE value even though I’ve clicked on the checkbox. The other datagridviews (text and combobox) columns  work fine. Here is what I am doing…

OK, so I am dynamically creating datagridviews (DGVs) at runtime in my constructor based on how many tab sheets there are in the tab control which is determined by the number of weeks in any given date range i.e. one DGV per tab page (where you tab page for each week)

```
for (int i = 0; i < wcNumWeeks; i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in wbDatesDT.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(dr["tabNo"].ToString()) == i + 1)
        {
        wcDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["wcDate"].ToString());
        break;
        }
    }
    weeksTabControl.TabPages.Add(wcDate.ToShortDateString());
    weeksTabControl.TabPages[i].AutoScroll = true;
    weeksTabControl.TabPages[i].Width = 1500;
    weeksTabControl.TabPages[i].Height = 700;
    weeksTabControl.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(new DataGridView()
    {
        Name = "dataGridView" + (i + 1).ToString(),
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Width = 1450,
        Height = 650,
        Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right),
        ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both,
        AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells 
    });
}
```

Again in the **constructor**, for each datagridview created I am creating event as follows:

```
foreach (Control thisControl in weeksTabControl.Controls)
{
    if (thisControl.GetType() == typeof(TabPage))
    {
        foreach (Control dgv in thisControl.Controls)
        {
        if (dgv.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
        {
            BuildWhiteboardDGV((DataGridView)dgv);
            PopulateWhiteboardDGV((DataGridView)dgv);
            wbDataGridView = (DataGridView)dgv;
            wbDataGridView.CellMouseUp += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(wbDataGridView_CellMouseUp);
            wbDataGridView.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(wbDataGridView_CellEndEdit);
            wbDataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(wbDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
            wbDataGridView.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(wbDataGridView_CellValueChanged);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

The events themselves are as follows:

```
void wbDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (wbDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
    wbDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
 
void wbDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 13 && e.ColumnIndex <= 15)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point cur = new System.Drawing.Point(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell curCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)wbDataGridView[cur.X, cur.Y];
        if (curCell.Value != null && (bool)(curCell.Value) == true)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
        }
        else if (curCell.Value != null && (bool)(curCell.Value) == false)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("FALSE");
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("NULL");
        }                   
    }
    return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex )
    {
    MessageBox.Show("wbDataGridView_CellValueChanged() ERROR - " + ex.Message + " --> " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
    return;
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything that made it not work for me. Your methods `wbDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` and `wbDataGridView_CellValueChanged` worked for me when I plugged them into a simple DataGridView with just one column as a checkbox column. I didn't see anything else in the rest of your posted code that looked like it would effect it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

OK.... I think I've sorted it.

In my CellMouseUp() event, I had not catered for the LEFT button.

Therefore, by now adding that, the CellValueChanged() event works correctly and captures the correct DataGridViewCheckCellColumn check state : TRUE when checked and FALSE when unchecked.

```
public void wbDataGridView_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left && e.RowIndex != -1) // added this and it now works
            {
                this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                this.colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
                this.wbDataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
                return;
            }

            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right && e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                this.colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
                this.wbDataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your comments though. Much appreciated.

Jobs a good un !!!!